# Copy Distinct Records Based on 3 Cols

Tags: sql-server

I have loads of data in a table called Temp. This data consists of duplicates.
Not Entire rows but the same data in 3 columns. They are HouseNo,DateofYear,TimeOfDay.

I want to copy only the distinct rows from "Temp" into another table, "ThermData."

Basically what i want to do is copy all the distinct rows from Temp to ThermData where distinct(HouseNo,DateofYear,TimeOfDay). Something like that.

I know we can't do that. An alternative to how i can do that.

Do help me out. I have tried lots of things but haven't solved got it.

---

Sample Data. Values which are repeated are like....
I want to delete the duplicate row based on the values of HouseNo,DateofYear,TimeOfDay

---

```
HouseNo DateofYear TimeOfDay Count
102 10/1/2009    0:00:02 AM 2
102 10/1/2009    1:00:02 AM 2
102 10/1/2009    10:00:02 AM    2
```

Comment: You want to copy only those rows where there aren't any duplicates? Or, there's some rule (you've not included in your question) for how to reduce those rows where there are duplicates down to a single row? It's not very clear from your question (to me). Maybe add some sample data and expected results?

Comment: Not exactly clear what you mean by distinct in this case. Do you mean don't copy if it appears more than once or copy only 1 of the those records if it appears more than once?

Comment: Still not clear I'm afraid.  All records are distinct in your example. Could you show a before and after table?

Comment: example you have in temp table 2 records: `(1, 10/1/2009, 0:00:02 AM, col 4 some data 1, col5 some data 1)` and `(1, 10/1/2009, 0:00:02 AM, col 4 some data 2, col5 some data 2)`. You need 1 record in result with 5 columns. Wich data for columns 4 and 5 you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Northwind example based on the Orders table.

There are duplicates based on the (EmployeeID , ShipCity , ShipCountry) columns.

If you only execute the code between these 2 lines:

```
/* Run everything below this line to show crux of the fix */
/* Run everything above this line to show crux of the fix */
```

you'll see how it works. Basically:

(1) You run a GROUP BY on the 3 columns of interest.  **(derived1Duplicates)**

(2) Then you join back to the table using these 3 columns. **(on  ords.EmployeeID = derived1Duplicates.EmployeeID and  ords.ShipCity = derived1Duplicates.ShipCity and  ords.ShipCountry = derived1Duplicates.ShipCountry)**

(3) Then for each group, you tag them with Cardinal numbers (1,2,3,4,etc) **(using ROW_NUMBER())**

(4) Then you keep the row in each group that has the cardinal number of "1". **(where derived2DuplicatedEliminated.RowIDByGroupBy = 1)**

```
    Use Northwind
    GO


declare @DestinationVariableTable table ( 
    NotNeededButForFunRowIDByGroupBy int not null ,
    NotNeededButForFunDuplicateCount int not null ,
    [OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [nchar](5) NULL,
    [EmployeeID] [int] NULL,
    [OrderDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [RequiredDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ShippedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ShipVia] [int] NULL,
    [Freight] [money] NULL,
    [ShipName] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [ShipAddress] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [ShipCity] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [ShipRegion] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [ShipPostalCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [ShipCountry] [nvarchar](15) NULL
)


INSERT INTO @DestinationVariableTable (NotNeededButForFunRowIDByGroupBy , NotNeededButForFunDuplicateCount , OrderID,CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,RequiredDate,ShippedDate,ShipVia,Freight,ShipName,ShipAddress,ShipCity,ShipRegion,ShipPostalCode,ShipCountry )

Select RowIDByGroupBy , MyDuplicateCount , OrderID,CustomerID,EmployeeID,OrderDate,RequiredDate,ShippedDate,ShipVia,Freight,ShipName,ShipAddress,ShipCity,ShipRegion,ShipPostalCode,ShipCountry
From
(
/* Run everything below this line to show crux of the fix */
Select
 RowIDByGroupBy = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ords.EmployeeID , ords.ShipCity , ords.ShipCountry ORDER BY ords.OrderID )
 , derived1Duplicates.MyDuplicateCount
, ords.* 
from
  [dbo].[Orders] ords
 join
 (
select EmployeeID , ShipCity , ShipCountry , COUNT(*) as MyDuplicateCount from [dbo].[Orders] GROUP BY EmployeeID , ShipCity , ShipCountry /*HAVING COUNT(*) > 1*/
) as derived1Duplicates
on  ords.EmployeeID = derived1Duplicates.EmployeeID and  ords.ShipCity = derived1Duplicates.ShipCity and  ords.ShipCountry = derived1Duplicates.ShipCountry 
/* Run everything above this line to show crux of the fix */
)
as derived2DuplicatedEliminated
where derived2DuplicatedEliminated.RowIDByGroupBy = 1

select * from @DestinationVariableTable
```

*emphasized text**emphasized text**emphasized text*